# Deserializing non-polimorphic structure from network packet

Tags: c++, network-programming, protocols

I'm developing network protocol. I have a lot of non-polimorphic structures. I need to pass input structure to packet with its id(unique number of structure) and serialize it to byte array to send.
And deserialize it the same: receive byte array, get structure id, and deserialize bytes as this structure.

How?

Example with comments:

```
// Internal structure, cannot be edited
struct FirstProcedureParams {
    std::string some_string;
    int some_integer;
};

// Also cannot be edited
struct SecondProcedureParams {
    std::vector<int> some_vector;
    std::map<int, int> some_map;
};

// My class to serialize and deserialize packet data to send to client or server.
class CallProcedurePacket : public BasePacket {
    public:
    void Serialize(uint8_t** bytes, size_t* length) override;
    
    void Deserialize(const uint8_t* bytes, size_t length) override;
    
    public:
    int procedure_id; // for example, 1 - FirstProcedureParams, 2 - SecondProcedureParams.
    
    // there is must be parameters for concrete procedure id.
};

void CallProcedurePacket::Serialize(uint8_t** bytes, size_t* length) {
    // Some stuff..
    
    writer.Write(procedure_id);
    
    // How can I write dynamic parameters structure
    // If it is not polymorphic and it hasn't method like Serialize?
    // In this example only 2 structures: FirstProcedureParams and SecondProcedureParams.
    // But in real code I have more than 15 structures.
}

void CallProcedurePacket::Deserialize(const uint8_t* bytes, size_t length) {
    // Some stuff..
    
    reader.Read(procedure_id);
    
    // I need to get FirstProcedureParams if procedure_id equal 1 
    // or SecondProcedureParams if procedure_id equal 2.
}

// -----------------------------

// Example of using CallProcedurePacket:
void SomeSendFunction() {
    FirstProcedureParams params;
    params.some_string = "some string";
    params.some_integer = 789;
    
    CallProcedurePacket call_procedure_packet;
    call_procedure_packet.procedure_id = 1;
    call_procedure_packet.params = params; // what type should be `params` field? how can I write FirstProcedureParams to it?
    
    SendPacket(call_procedure_packet);
}

void SomeSendFunction2() {
    SecondProcedureParams params;
    params.some_vector = { 1, 2, 3 };
    params.some_map = {
        { 1, 5 },
        { 7, 9 }
    };
    
    CallProcedurePacket call_procedure_packet;
    call_procedure_packet.procedure_id = 2;
    call_procedure_packet.params = params; // params field should accept SecondProcedureParams too.
    
    SendPacket(call_procedure_packet);
}

// And reading..
void SomeReceiveFunction() {
    CallProcedurePacket call_procedure_packet = ReceivePacket();
    
    if (call_procedure_packet.procedure_id == 1) {
        FirstProcedureParams params;
        // somehow get the params.
        
        procedure(params.some_string, params.some_integer);
    }
    else if (call_procedure_packet.procedure_id == 2) {
        SecondProcedureParams params;
        
        // some usage of params.
    }
}
```

Comment: You are more or less reinventing [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers), and in particular their [`oneof` feature](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec#oneof_and_oneof_field). Consider using protobufs instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: I think you should clarify first of all to yourself whether you are developing a custom serialization library or a communication protocol, they are [different](https://commschamp.github.io/articles/2019/01/05/communication-more-than-serialization/), but sharing some common features, such as requiring a lot of boilerplate code. Manually writing such code is bad idea, that's why various code generators are recommended. If it's serialization, use protobuf or similar. In case it's actual communication protocol use something like [CommsChampion Ecosystem](https://commschamp.github.io/)